# As 'host' is deprecated for manifest.yml - how to configure a standard scapp.io route?

Tags: swisscomdev

CF CLI now warns with a deprecation message:

```
Deprecation warning: Route component attributes 'domain', 'domains', 'host', 'hosts' and 'no-hostname' are deprecated. Found: host.
```

My manifest.yml looks like that currently:

```
applications:
- host: myexample-test
```

which results in a final route like: **myexample-test.scapp.io**

how to define this exact same route with the new manifest *routes* config?

These examples are taken from the cloudfoundry docs but I am not sure whether swisscomdev is adopting anything behind the scenes?

```
routes:
- route: example.com
- route: www.example.com/foo
- route: tcp-example.com:1234
```

**UPDATE**

Just tried it with suggested solution and this manifest:

```
applications:
  routes:
  - route: myexample-test.scapp.io
  name: MyExample
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  instances: 1
  memory: 64M
```

which resulted in the following error message:

> yaml: unmarshal errors:
>     line 2: cannot unmarshal !!map into []manifest.Application

Comment: I still think the previous syntax is better, however cloud foundry changed it based 135 survy and decided to change it. https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/coming-changes-app-manifest-simplification/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swisscom Application cloud does not do something special behind the scenes, so you can apply what's written in the CF CLI docs. 
If we're doing something other than vanilla CF, we will mention this in our docs.

I quickly checked it, the following does the trick for your route:

```
routes:
- route: myexample-test.scapp.io
```

In your example, note that `applications` must be an array of maps, so make sure the first element key contains a `-`, otherwise it's treated as a map.

Full example:

```
applications:
- name: MyExample
  routes:
  - route: myexample-test.scapp.io
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  instances: 1
  memory: 64M
```